# Get the computed style of a DOM element

Tags: java, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

After a layout is completed, I want to parse through the DOM tree and get the computed styles of each element. Is this possible.

The closest I could get is the below snippet, but it gives only uncomputed styles.

```
Element elm = (Element) _doc.getElementsByTagName("table").item(0);
Map props = _sharedContext.getCss().getCascadedPropertiesMap(elm);
```

Is it also possible to get which "**Box**" the element lies in.

Comment: Did you try JSOUP.http://jsoup.org/. Best DOM parser with Jquery equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the computed style in the document with `ITextRenderer.getRootBox()`.

This method return a tree of `org.xhtmlrenderer.render.Box` objects which you can scan to find your element.

You can get the box computed style with `Box.getStyle()` and you can get the element the box refers to with `Box.getElement()`.